# How do I introduce segmentation fault to ruby?

Tags: ruby, compilation, segmentation-fault

Currently, I am doing research on the debugging method of the interpreter as the case of the crash is due to the faulty development in the Ruby interpreter.

In order for me to test my method, I need to introduce the known bug within the interpreter itself. Thus, I would like to introduce a bug (specifically seg. fault) and let the ruby to crash with a correct (or valid input file). This seg. fault needs to happen because of the interpreter and/or mJIT of the Ruby itself, not the input *.rb program, so I am assuming that the Ruby interpreter is the source of the issue and debug it.

However, whenever I modify the source code and re-compile the ruby with `$sudo make install`, the compilation gets aborted with an error below:

```
generating encdb.h
miniruby: io.c:4737: rb_io_fptr_finalize_internal: Assertion `idx < 10' failed.
uncommon.mk:1032: recipe for target 'encdb.h' failed
make: *** [encdb.h] Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code added in the source code is like below (This is not an example of Seg. fault):

```
    int idx;
    idx = rand() % 1000 + 100;
    assert (idx < 10);
```

This is syntatically correct and should not complain during the compilation time, but asserts at the runtime.

My guess is that the ruby pre-compiles the interpreter once and runs it with miniruby, then if any error occurs during that run, it aborts the entire compilation (make) procedure.

I know this is a somewhat complicated issue but does anyone can help me how to get over this problem by able to compile with any code modification to introduce the bug?

Comment: _"I need to introduce the known bug within the interpreter itself"_ – if it is a known bug, just get the Ruby version containing that bug. Alternatively, you could create a gem with a native extension to cause the segmentation fault, so you don't have to patch Ruby itself.